# int[] to string c#

Tags: c#, c++

Hi I'm developing an client application in C# and the server is written in c++

the server uses:

```
inline void StrToInts(int *pInts, int Num, const char *pStr)
{
  int Index = 0;
  while(Num)
  {
    char aBuf[4] = {0,0,0,0};
    for(int c = 0; c < 4 && pStr[Index]; c++, Index++)
      aBuf[c] = pStr[Index];
    *pInts = ((aBuf[0]+128)<<24)|((aBuf[1]+128)<<16)|((aBuf[2]+128)<<8)|(aBuf[3]+128);
    pInts++;
    Num--;
  }

  // null terminate
  pInts[-1] &= 0xffffff00;
}
```

to convert an string to int[]

in my c# client i recieve:

```
int[4] { -14240, -12938, -16988, -8832 }
```

How do I convert the array back to an string?
I don't want to use unsafe code (e.g. pointers)
Any of my tries resulted in unreadable strings.

EDIT:
Here is one of my approch:

```
private string IntsToString(int[] ints)
{
  StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
  for (int i = 0; i < ints.Length; i++)
  {
    byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(ints[i]);
    for (int j = 0; j < bytes.Length; j++)
      s.Append((char)(bytes[j] & 0x7F));
  }
  return s.ToString();
}
```

I know I need to take care of endianess but as the server is running on my local machine and the server too, I assume that this is not a problem.
My other try was to use an struct with explicit layout and same FieldOffset for integer and chars but it doesn't work, either.

Comment: How the result string should look like?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please share your code, I'm expecting something what already does all bit shifts

Comment: Do you want to return an array of string or a single string (csv)

Comment: I edited my question and added a code snippet of my idea.
I want to get an string back.
And I'm not sure what the right result for my given example should be :-(

Comment: Pointers are not unsafe.  No more so than any other data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try something like (using LINQ):

```
int[] fromServer = { -14240, -12938, -16988, -8832, };

string reconstructedStr = new string(fromServer.SelectMany(BitConverter.GetBytes).Select(b => (char)(b - 128)).ToArray());
```

Untested, but there's something to start from. Don't know if the subtraction of `128` is correct.

Comment: It returns "￠H￶M$=\0]". Strange :)
I think there needs to be a kind of stop if we got a NUL (because its the end of a string)

Comment: @RobinWebdev Did you expect another string? Which one? You're right my approach doesn't stop after a `'\0'` character. Maybe the order of the `char` is not correct in my version either, but the characters should be the same as you want? If you want to delete the first `'\0'` and everything after it, maybe try `reconstructedStr = reconstructedStr.Remove(reconstructedStr.IndexOf('\0'));` (will fail if no `'\0'` is there).

Comment: I expected something more readable because the string gets drawed to the screen. Hmpf...

Comment: @RobinWebdev Maybe the server code isn't correct? I don't know why the server and client must exchange strings in such a hand-coded way.

Comment: Ther server works with other clients well, so I think the problem has to be client-side... I trust you that your example works, so try to find a mistake elsewhere...could take some time :)

Comment: ok I think I found the problem. It occurs in my extraction process only for high numbers so i didn't recognized it before. 
Now the bytes are still reversed but that's a smaller problem. Thank's for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a comma separated string this way:

```
string str = String.Join(", ", intArray.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray());
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need the string as it exists server-side. The task is to reverse the C++ function but in C# without pointers.

Comment: No it's a private project I work on. I left school a few years ago :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    var ints = new[] {-14240, -12938, -16988, -8832};
    var result = string.Join("-", ints.Select(i => BitConverter.ToString(BitConverter.GetBytes(i))));
    Console.WriteLine(result); //60-C8-FF-FF-76-CD-FF-FF-A4-BD-FF-FF-80-DD-FF-FF
```

`BitConverter.ToString` can be replaced by something else here, depending on how you will parse string later.

Comment: Not bad, but I think you missing the +128 in the C++ code.
In my opinion its sets the last bit in every byte so I need to unset the bit during convertion back? This would make each byte represent an printable ASCII character. Correct me if I'm wrong please...